# Conky does not starting automatically after boot

Tags: conky

In start up applications I already given a command to start Conky automatically after boot.But it does not starting after boot automatically.I have to manually start it every time.Please help.

Comment: How did you configure conkey to start? You probably need to configure it to start after X , perhaps when you log in.

Comment: You may use update-rc.d to set start it at boot

Comment: @d0lph1n conky needs X, it won't work from the init scripts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classic issue with `conky`. the solution is usually to have it wait a few seconds. One way to do this is to write a script that calls `conky` with a delay and add *that* to your startup applications instead of `conky` itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Wait 10 seconds
sleep 20

## Run conky
conky
```

Save the script above as (for example) `$HOME/start_conky.sh`, make it executable (`chmod +x $HOME/start_conky.sh`) and then add it to your startup applications instead of `conky`.

Comment: @user259975 please [edit] your question and show exactly how you added this to your startup applications. Also, try adding `echo "started" > ~/conky.log` to the script, that will print a `started` into the file `~/conky.log` which should let you know if the script is being executed.

Comment: sudo -i
[sudo] password for amol: 
root@4M01:~# chmod +x start_conky.sh
root@4M01:~#

Comment: and in start up I have added the file start_conky.sh

Comment: @user259975 1) As I said before, please **[edit]** your question, to show _exactly_ how you added it. Ideally, give a screenshot so we can see the format you used to add the script to your startup files. 2) Do **not** use `sudo`, it is not necessary and it is a bad idea. When you use `sudo -i` you move to root's home directory, not yours, you are in `/root` so, presumably so is your script. You have not shown how you added the file, did you use the whole path or just the name? Nut in any case, the file is probably in `/root` and not in your `$HOME`.

Comment: sorry..but i am unable to post screen pic.I don't have 10 reputations :(

Comment: @user259975 That's OK, you can either describe it (by editing your question), tell me exactly what you put in the "Command" field. Or you can upload a picture to a service like http://imgur.com and give a link to it. Anyway, did you try this again but _without using sudo_?

Comment: sorry but I can't vote up.I don't have 15 reputation :(

Comment: This time I didn't used sudo..sudo was the problem

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to add it to your `Startup Applications` and use the `-p` or `--pause=SECONDS` argument.

[image]

Open `Startup Applications`

[image]

Click <kbd>Add</kbd> and enter the following:

[image]

Where `-p10` means wait 10 seconds after boot to start `Conky`
You can also use `conky --pause=10`
Or set the timeout to whatever you feel comfortable with

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use Conky Manager.

[image: conky manager settings]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Kubuntu 20.04.
The solution was to edit configurations in `/etc/conky/conky.conf`:

```
own_window_type = 'normal',
own_window_hints = 'undecorated,sticky,below,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
```

Use `man -P "less -p 'CONFIGURATION SETTINGS'"` terminal command for more detail information about Conky's configuration sittings.

Answer (score 0):

alternative:
change Command-line in 'Startup Application Preference'for chonky to
'conky--deamonize--pause=10'

I think, this is the simplest solution